# How to import selective rows from a table into an oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database which has a table named 'X' and I have another database which is almost similar to the database 'X' (having exactly same tables and the schema of all tables also being same). Only data in the tables are different. Now I want to copy a few selective rows from a table. Is there a provision by which I can put a 'where' clause in the import statement  so that only those rows are imported which satisfy the 'where' condition.

Comment: what are you using to do the import? `INSERT INTO`, `imp`, `impdp`, or something else?

Comment: @Jeffrey: I want to use `imp` to import from a .dmp file

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure we can do it..See below its just an example

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.Field1=destTable.Field1 and
                       SrcTable.Field2=DestTable.Field2...etc.)
                 )
```

Comment: I have an export of the database (.dmp file) I have to import from this file. I don't think the above command helps in my case.

Comment: You cant use sql query for .dmp file export..Try exporting as .sql file.Open the .sql file in text editor.And replace the table name .and run the sql file.

Comment: You don't get me I don't have to use an sql query . I have to use an `imp` command to import a few specific rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional QUERY parameter to exp, e.g.:

```
exp scott/tiger TABLES=emp QUERY=\"WHERE job=\'SALESMAN\' and sal \<1600\"
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1005842

I don't think you can filter it on import, though. You could import into a staging schema, then copy the data across with SQL.